# how to update mac python without reinstall modules

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

First,sorry for my poor English!
I encountered with some troubles during I updated my python.
My original mac python 2.7.6 still remain the same. However,after I installed python 2.7.9 as app, python 2.7.9 became my default python. That is, when I typed python -V instruction, Python 2.7.9 showed.
But those modules I had installed could not be imported by Python 2.7.9. For example, I did install numpy when I used python 2.7.6, but "No module named numpy" showed after I install python 2.7.9.
My point is how to link app python 2.7.9 to those modules? I didn't delete orignal mac python, and I want to fix this problem without doing so. Of course, if deleting original mac python do good to me, I will do so. Thank you for help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Some modules have to be recompiled for your specific Python version. That's why they are kept separate.

Comment: @tripleee not for changes in micro versions. Packages compiled with 2.7.6 will work fine with 2.7.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:*** the following answer is assuming that you installed Python 2.7.9 from the installer downloaded from python.org. If you used Homebrew, MacPorts, Anaconda, or some other distribution, these instructions will not work.

---

If you haven't installed any 3rd-party modules into 2.7.9 yet, the solution is pretty easy. First, from the command line, run

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
```

and then

```
ls site-packages
```

to verify that there's nothing in 2.7.9's `site-packages` folder except a `README` file. Then run

```
sudo rm -rf site-packages
```

to delete the folder. Finally, we'll symlink it to (what I believe is) your current `site-packages` location:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

and you should be all set. Test by firing up 2.7.9 and trying to `import numpy`, for example. It should work just fine.

Comment: thanks! what if there are easy_install.py(pth)(pyc)(pyo),pkg_resources.py(pyc)(pyo) and setuptools(setuptools-7.0.dist-info) in site-packages? And I wonder if both 2.7.6's site-packages and 2.7.6's site-packages are the same? Or 2.7.6's site-packages resides in /System/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7?

Comment: @AlexChang the `setuptools` packages should be fine, you can reinstall them with `pip` (which now comes with 2.7.9). The `site-packages` for 2.7.6 and 2.7.9 are not the same: for a python.org install of 2.7.9, `site-packages` is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`, while for Apple's system version of Python it's in `/Library/Python/2.7`. Now, directories like `/System/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7` are still very important, and certainly should **not** be removed, but none of the other entries in `sys.path` contain `site-packages`.

Comment: @AlexChang regarding deleting the contents of `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` - now that I think about it, before deleting the directory entirely, enter it and run `sudo mv * /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` to move everything to the other location. If the prompt asks, you do want to overwrite the existing files. Then go up one directory, delete `site-packages`, then create the symlink before using `pip` again.

Comment: Thanks! It did work! I copied /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages and created a symlink. Then I moved those files in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages into the directory linked by symlink.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> PYTHONPATH
>   Augment the default search path for module files. The
>   format is the same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory
>   pathnames separated by os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix [or OSX] or semicolons
>   on Windows). Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

The "default search path for module files" is a list of directories that you can see by executing the following line in the Terminal App:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

You can set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to the directory containing the old modules.  You can set environment variables inside the file:

```
~/.bashrc
```

First, you have to figure out where the old modules are located.  If you installed the old version of python, then they will be located approximately here:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7.6/site-packages

If the old version is the system install of python, then the directory path to the old modules will be:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

(credit to @MattDMo for figuring out that path)

Open Finder and follow the appropriate path until you find the old modules.

Once you have the path to the old modules, edit your .bashrc file.  Open up Terminal App (then if necessary cd to your home directory).  Then type `ls -al`:

> ~$ ls -al

See if .bashrc is listed.  If it exists, then open it in your favorite programming text editor, .e.g.

> ~$ vim .bashrc

If the .bashrc file doesn't exist, then that command will create the file. Next, add the following line to the bottom of .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/the rest of the path here"
```

Note: There cannot be spaces on either side of the equals sign.

If there are already lines in .bashrc that assign to PYTHONPATH, then do this instead:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Library/the rest of the path here:$PYTHONPATH"
```

That adds the directory to the front of the colon separated list of directories that have already been assigned to PYTHONPATH.

Save the file, quit the Terminal application, then try to execute a python program that imports one of the old modules.

Comment: Thanks! I do have /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
but there is no python2.7.6 but libpython2.7.dylib, pkgconfig, and python2.7. What should I do?

Comment: I think you should look in python2.7 for your old modules.

Comment: Thanks!But there is no site-packages in my  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7

Comment: @AlexChang see my answer and comment for the correct location of `site-packages`.

Comment: @AlexChang, Are the old modules in `.../python2.7`?

Comment: For future searchers, the System python installs modules at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, so that is the path you should assign to PYTHONPATH.